# What do I change to make the Sandwich Maker problem more efficient?

Tags: python

The problem statment requires me to write a program that asks user for their sandwich preferences using PyInputPlus. Use inputMenu to get bread, protein info. InputYesNo to for cheese topping and inputInt to get qty of sandwiches. And finally calculate the cost of the sandwich as per all selection. Come up with your own prices.
How can I improve my program. This program works but only for 1 kind of cheese and 1 kind of topping. What changes should I make to make the program calculate the total for multiple cheeses and toppings.

```
import pyinputplus as pypi 

prices = {'Bread':{'Wheat':2, 'White':2, 'Sourdough':3},
          'Protein':{'Chicken':2, 'Turkey':3, 'Ham':3, 'Tofu':2},
          'Cheese':{'Cheddar':1, 'Swiss':1, 'Mozzerella':1},
          'Topping':{'Mayo':0, 'Mustard':0,'Lettuce':1, 'Tomato':1}}
totalPrice = []
bread = pypi.inputMenu(['Wheat','White','Sourdough'],prompt="What kind of Bread would you like?\n",default=None, caseSensitive=False)
breadPrice = prices['Bread'][bread]
totalPrice = breadPrice
protien = pypi.inputMenu(['Chicken', 'Turkey','Ham','Tofu'],prompt="What kind of protein would you like?\n",default=None, caseSensitive=False)
totalPrice += prices['Protein'][protien]
cheese = pypi.inputYesNo("Do you want cheese? Yes/No:\n ", yesVal="yes", noVal="no", caseSensitive=False, default=None, blank=False,)
if cheese == 'yes':
    kindofcheese = pypi.inputMenu(['Cheddar', 'Swiss', 'Mozzerella'],prompt="What kind of cheese would you like?\n",default=None, caseSensitive=False)
    totalPrice += prices['Cheese'][kindofcheese]
else:
    print('No cheese selected')

topping = pypi.inputYesNo("Do you want any toppings? Yes/No:\n", yesVal="yes", noVal="no", caseSensitive=False, default=None, blank=False)
if topping == 'yes':
    kindoftopping=pypi.inputMenu(['Mayo', 'Mustard','Tomato','Lettuce'], prompt="What kind of topping would you like?\n",default=None,caseSensitive=False)
    totalPrice+=prices['Topping'][kindoftopping]
else:
    print('No topping selected')

Qty = pypi.inputInt(prompt="How many sandwiches would you like?\n", default=1, blank=False,min=1, lessThan=5)
totalPrice = totalPrice*Qty
print(f"The total amount payable for your sandwich(es) is {totalPrice}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a while loop to add cheese/topping until user enters no.
Here's the code for cheese, modify your code for toppings accordingly.

```
cheese = 'yes'  # initialize to get the loop running
while cheese == 'yes':  # ask for (additional) cheese until they enter no
    cheese = pypi.inputYesNo("Do you want cheese? Yes/No:\n ", yesVal="yes", noVal="no", caseSensitive=False, default=None, blank=False,)
    if cheese == 'yes':
        kindofcheese = pypi.inputMenu(['Cheddar', 'Swiss', 'Mozzerella'],prompt="What kind of cheese would you like?\n",default=None, caseSensitive=False)
        totalPrice += prices['Cheese'][kindofcheese]
    else:
        print('No (more) cheese selected')  # slightly modified status text
```